# RabbitMQ setExpiration(); property

Tags: rabbitmq

Hello Friends i want to know about the expriation Property in RabbitMQ. And what happens if I do not set this property. I am new in rabbitMQ please help me.

```
AMQP.BasicProperties properties = new AMQP.BasicProperties();
properties.setExpiration("432000000");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

> A TTL can be specified on a per-message basis, by setting the
>   expiration field in the basic AMQP class when sending a basic.publish.
>
> The value of the expiration field describes the TTL period in
>   milliseconds. The same constraints as for x-message-ttl apply. Since
>   the expiration field must be a string, the broker will (only) accept
>   the string representation of the number.

Suppose you set `Expiration` time = 1000

If no one consumes the message within 1 second the message will be dropped.

You can handle the "dropped" messages using https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html.

if you don't set the `Expiration` the message remains to the queue for ever (if there aren't consumers).

**EDIT**

Added the comment by theMayer

*The messages are not dropped until they reach the head of the queue - therefore, if a non-expiring message exists prior to the message in the queue, no messages will self-delete until the non-expiring message is consumed.*

read also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991503/messages-with-expiration-are-not-removed-from-rabbitmq/) post

Comment: This is true with a caveat. The messages are not dropped until they reach the head of the queue - therefore, if a non-expiring message exists prior to the message in the queue, no messages will self-delete until the non-expiring message is consumed.